# When J's history is erased do they do so with the knowledge that Jeebs knows his identity?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black

Before being inducted into MiB, K takes J into Jeebs' Pawn Shop. Jeebs calls him "Officer Edwards" (Knowing J's name)

Jeebs obviously knows J from his pre-MiB life. When J's history is erased do they do so with the knowledge that Jeebs knows his identity?

The neutralizer can wipe backwards but doesn't seem to have selective memory removal. (To get rid of J's life in Jeebs head would require blanking Jeebs to before he ever met J)

Comment: I wonder if, because he is already a *part* of that world, they entrust him with that information.  Because releasing that, would expose himself as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I think that @tylershads hit the Jeebs on the head](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/mib-jeebs-memory-question#comment3360_2277):

> I wonder if, because he is already a part of that world, they entrust him with that information. Because releasing that, would expose himself as well?

When J was erased, everything that consisted of his **human** existence was erased.  If Jeebs only knew him through J’s law enforcement duties he probably doesn’t have any personal information on J, making it almost impossible for Jeebs to find out any other information.  He would have to do a lot of leg work to find out any information from people still alive that knew J (police also don’t share personal information very freely), and doing so would probably put him on MIB’s hot list, which I think is enough to force Jeebs to keep the information to himself.